# How can I create a simple input validator by using ANTLR?

Tags: java, antlr, validation, antlr3

I wrote my grammar in ANTLRWorks and it worked pretty well and then I generated lexer and parser.

Well the code executes and there's no error.

But it makes me crazy even with a wrong input everything is fine. By this I mean that `parser.prog()` executes just fine. So where is the information that I should get as the result? I just want to check the input to figure it out that if it is a propositional logic statement or not?

I used the below to generate the code but it had some errors like it can not find the main class!

```
java antlr.jar org.antlr.Tool PropLogic.g
```

But this code worked :

```
java -cp antlr.jar org.antlr.Tool PropLogic.g
```

Here's the Grammar :

```
    grammar PropLogic;

    NOT : '!' ;
    OR  : '+' ;
    AND : '.' ;
    IMPLIES : '->' ;
    SYMBOLS : ('a'..'z') | '~' ;
    OP : '(' ;
    CP : ')' ;

prog    : formula ;


formula : NOT formula
    | OP formula( AND formula CP | OR formula CP | IMPLIES formula CP)
    | SYMBOLS ;


WHITESPACE : ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C' )+    { $channel = HIDDEN; } ;
```

Here's my code:

```
import org.antlr.runtime.ANTLRStringStream;
import org.antlr.runtime.CommonTokenStream;

public class Tableaux {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream("a b c");
        PropLogicLexer lexer = new PropLogicLexer(in);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        PropLogicParser parser = new PropLogicParser(tokens);
        parser.prog();
    }

}
```

Comment: There must be something wrong with your grammar.

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler, probably the opposite. @Amirh, if, after parsing your input, nothing is printed to the console, it means your parser did not find any errors in said input. If you want your parser to actually _do_ something (return a `boolean` or display a log message to the STDOUT), you must instruct it to do so. Perhaps you want to post your grammar, the input you're parsing, and what you expect, or hope to get in return.

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler, well antlrworks says the grammer is ok. and I generated lexer and parser with no error. @Bart Kiers with any input parser generates no output to the console.

Comment: @Amirh: What do you mean by "no error"? Did you ensure that your grammar is correct? Also, as @Bart said, have you instructed the parser to output anything when the input is incorrect?

Comment: @ Jeremy Heiler. No but it seems that it does nothing to the input. btw I edited the question and you can see the grammar.

Comment: _"... any input parser generates no output to the console ..."_, it _does_ produce errors if you provide tokens you did not define in your lexer, of course. Try parsing the string: `"A"`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following test class:

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream(args[0]);
    PropLogicLexer lexer = new PropLogicLexer(in);
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    PropLogicParser parser = new PropLogicParser(tokens);
    parser.prog();
  }
}
```

which can be invoked on *nix/MacOS like this:

```
java -cp .:antlr-3.2.jar Main "a b c"
```

or on Windows

```
java -cp .;antlr-3.2.jar Main "a b c"
```

does not produce any errors because your parser *and* lexer are "content" with the input. The lexer tokenizes the input into the following 3 tokens `a`, `b` and `c` (spaces are ignored). And the parser rule:

```
prog
  :  formula 
  ;
```

matches a single `formula`, which in its turn matches a `SYMBOLS` token. Note that although you named it `SYMBOLS` (plural), it only matches a single lower case letter, or tilde (`~`):

```
SYMBOLS : ('a'..'z') | '~' ;
```

So, in short, from the input source `"a b c"`, only `a` is being parsed by your parser. You probably want your parser to consume the entire token stream, which can be done by adding the `EOF` (end of file) token after the entry point of your grammar:

```
prog
  :  formula EOF
  ;
```

If you run the test class again and provide `"a b c"` as input, the following error is produced:

```
line 1:2 missing EOF at 'b'
```

### EDIT

I tested you grammar including the `EOF` token:

```
grammar PropLogic;

prog
  :  formula EOF
  ;

formula 
  :  NOT formula
  |  OP formula (AND formula CP | OR formula CP | IMPLIES formula CP)
  |  SYMBOLS
  ;

NOT : '!' ;
OR  : '+' ;
AND : '.' ;
IMPLIES : '->' ;
SYMBOLS : ('a'..'z') | '~' ;
OP : '(' ;
CP : ')' ;
WHITESPACE : ('\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C')+ { $channel = HIDDEN; } ;
```

with the class including the `ANTLRStringStream`:

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream("a b c");
    PropLogicLexer lexer = new PropLogicLexer(in);
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    PropLogicParser parser = new PropLogicParser(tokens);
    parser.prog();
  }
}
```

with both ANTLR 3.2, and ANTLR 3.3:

```
java -cp antlr-3.2.jar org.antlr.Tool PropLogic.g 
javac -cp antlr-3.2.jar *.java
java -cp .:antlr-3.2.jar Main
line 1:2 missing EOF at 'b'

java -cp antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool PropLogic.g 
javac -cp antlr-3.3.jar *.java
java -cp .:antlr-3.3.jar Main
line 1:2 missing EOF at 'b'
```

And as you can see, both produce the error message:

```
line 1:2 missing EOF at 'b'
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I haven't tested it yet, but you already added my knowledge.

Comment: @Amirh, you're welcome. Feel free to post back if something is unclear, or doesn't work as you expect (or create a new question, of course!). Good luck!

Comment: actually I tested "a b c" and there's nothing in console. by the way. I just a string variable as an input to ANTLRStringStream. I don't use the command line in this case.

Comment: @Bart Kiers, Thanks for your time but I'm experiencing difficulties. :(

Comment: @Amirh, well, I explained why `"a b c"` produces no errors. Or are you saying you don't get any error(s) even when you include the EOF token? I find that hard to believe... In the latter case, please edit your original question and post **1)** the exact grammar you use, **2)** the Java class you're using to test the parser and **3)** tell me what version of ANTLR you're using.

Comment: @Bart Kiers, oh, sorry my bad. I'm using Antlr 3.3. I just updated the question with my java code. the grammar is exactly what I posted. there are just some more comments.

Comment: @Bart Kiers, you mean when I enter a wrong input, it just count the first character as a SYMBOLS and accepts it?

Comment: Yes, `"a b c"` is accepted because your `prog` rule matches a single `formula`, and a single `formula` matches a single `SYMBOLS` token (the `a`, in this case). You never "tell" your parser to match more than that.

Comment: @Bart Kiers, You were right, I added EOF. and it totally works! now I just have to work to get a boolean result. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Amirh, you're welcome (I was editing my answer when you posted your last comment...).

Comment: I want to add some no parenthesis parser rules. btw is there a way to point to an element in the input based on the rules? for example I want to convert all 'and' and 'or' statements to their equvalent '->' statement.

Comment: My current answer pretty much answers your present question (I presume), so I recommend that we leave these small "comment boxes" for comments only because you can't put a decent detailed question in it. If you have another (ANTLR related) question, feel free to post a new question here on SO. If you tag it with ANTLR, I'll (most likely) see it floating by! :)

Comment: Ok. After sending my new question, I'll send its' link here right below your comments.

Comment: No problem Amirh. Make sure you create your new question as this question is: grammar _and_ test class included! :)

Comment: @Bart Kiers, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522574/what-is-the-equivalent-for-sigmanull-in-antlr-bnf-grammar-notation